# Mysqli prepared statement function in class

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to make prepared statement function in class, so how I could make some DRY code. After this, I want to try to make CRUD system with prepared statements, but one thing bogus me..

//Class method

```
        public function Insert($SQL, $types=array()){
                $count = count($types);
                $params = implode(',', $types);
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->link, $SQL);

                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $params, ???);

                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            }
$SQL = "INSERT INTO users (username, password,date_reg) VALUES(?,?, NOW())";
$arr= array('s','s');
$db->Insert($SQL, $arr);
```

So.. in line **mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $params, ???);**
how can I complete that statement, so that 3rd parameter works (I need to insert variables as bind params)
Sorry for bad english..

Comment: You are heading into the wrong direction with your desired to abstract things here. You try to abstract the abstraction which does not really make much sense. Specifically you devide the definition of the statement and its usage to separate locations in your logic which leads to the danger of issues just as you describe. So this simply is not a good idea. You do not need such a specific method `Insert`, since the sql statement itself is enough to execute such insert statement.

Comment: So it isn't possible this way?

Comment: It certainly is possible to craft something. I only say it is a bad idea, since it causes more problems that it soles. So why do it?

Comment: There are numerous comments [on the PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) about this.  Most use reflection, some are calling `call_user_func_array()` in a loop, etc.  But [@arkascha](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1248114/arkascha) is right, you are *abstracting* an abstraction - and getting no value from it!